# Trying to make browsersync work within vagrant using gulp

Tags: gulp, vagrant, browser-sync

I've been stuck in trying to make browsersync work within vagrant using gulp. I can connect to the UI of browsersync but I can never connect to my development site. If tried connecting using the address `http://localhost:3000`, I keep getting the error below:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Here are my configurations for vagrant:

```
  # IP Address to access the server 10.0.0.3
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.3"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001, auto_correct: true

  # Sync the server timezone to the host machine
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo rm /etc/localtime && sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Manila /etc/localtime", run: "always"

  # Sync File
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/html", mount_options: ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

Configuration when connecting to SQL

[image]

Here are my configurations for Gulp:

```
browserSync.init(["./assets/css/*.css"],{
    server: {
        proxy: "http://10.0.0.3/globe-gui/",
        open: false,
        port: "2222",
        injectChanges: true,
    }
});
```

[image]

I tried searching the net for a solution but can't seem to get an answer.

Comment: "I can connect to the UI of browsersync" How do you connect? In the host or guest? To what address?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule For the UI, i can connect using the following address - http://localhost:3001

Answer (score 2):

Browser sync isn't initialized with [the correct options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options).

```
browserSync.init({
    files: ["./assets/css/*.css"],
    open: false,
    port: "2222",
    injectChanges: true,
    proxy: "http://10.0.0.3/globe-gui/",   
});
```

Your `Vagrantfile` configures guest machine (box) to be accessible via IP address `10.0.0.3`.

Connect to services running in the box from host through IP address (`10.0.0.3`).

Set the SSH Host to `10.0.0.3` for a database service running on port `2222` in the box when *connecting from host to box*, but set `localhost` when connecting inside of the box.

I take it that `BrowserSync` is started inside the box.

Configure proxy to have value:

```
proxy: "http://localhost/globe-gui/",
```

Connect to `BrowserSync` from a browser running in the host through private IP address for box (`http://10.0.0.3:3000`).

Comment: I've tried this and I still get an error `Cannot GET /`